# Turn On ng-repeat element when loading repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a typical `ng-repeat` as you'll see below:

```
<button ng-repeat="tube in safeConfig.tubes" on-repeat-done="tubes_done" ng-class="{'btn btn-on' : tube.toggled, 'btn btn-off' : !tube.toggled}" ng-click="toggleBtn(tube, 'tube', $index)">{{tube.label}}</button>
```

As you can see when the button is clicked it runs a function to toggle the button on. It also adds an item to an array that is used in a custom filter to filter out items from a separate `ng-repeat` element.

I'm trying to figure out how to have the buttons in the `ng-repeat` already turned on when the page loads. The directive I have attached to the `ng-repeat` item is being called. the `filterData` service loads the array that holds the items that are filtering the list below:

```
secure.directive("toggleButtonOnLoad", ['filterData', function (filterData) {
    return {
        restriction: 'A',
        scope: {tube: '='}, 
        link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {

            var filterItems = filterData.getFilterItems();

            if ($scope.$last) {

                $scope.$emit(attributes["onRepeatDone"] || "repeat_done", element);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Is there a way to access the individual button and turn it on with the structure I've started? It seems wrong that `filterItems` would get called with every button, maybe extra unnecessary work. I need to essentially do something like `item.toggled` on each item if it is in the array.

*When I step through it I'm trying to access `element[0].innerText()` to compare it with items in the array. And it just shows the binding `{{tube.label}}`* Any way to show it evaluated?

Any thoughts or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding two attributes on my HTML

`device='tube' toggle-button-on-load=''`

Full HTML below:

```
<button ng-repeat="tube in safeConfig.tubes" device='tube' toggle-button-on-load='' ng-class="{'btn btn-on' : tube.toggled, 'btn btn-off' : !tube.toggled}" ng-click="toggleBtn(tube, 'tube', $index)">{{tube.label}}</button>
```

The directive gives me access to the `device`

```
secure.directive("toggleButtonOnLoad", ['filterData', 'utility', function (filterData, utility) {
    return {
        restriction: 'A',
        scope: { device: '=' },
        link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
            var filterItems = filterData.getFilterItems();
            if (filterItems.indexOf(utility.squish($scope.device.label)) !== -1) {
                $scope.device.toggled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

I can now access the object itself getting bound to the element and turn the toggle on/off depending on the arry returned from my service `getFilterItems()`.